# How to ORDER result according to user interaction

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table like name 'items'

```
id      sender  receiver        item
1       1       2               computer
2       2       1               mobile
3       1       3               ipad
4       4       1               ring
5       3       1               camera
6       1       8               pc
7       5       1               ring
8       1       10              tablet
```

The following query like

```
SELECT receiver id FROM items WHERE sender ='1'
UNION
SELECT sender FROM items WHERE receiver ='1'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

gives an order

```
10
8
5
4
3
2
```

If I want to get the order of sender/receiver with whom last interaction was happened by user Where sender/receiver=1, I mean the order (10, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2).

in the 8th row, the opponent for user=1, is 10

in the 7th row, the opponent for user=1, is 5

in the 6th row, the opponent for user=1, is 8

in the 5th&3rd, row the opponent for user=1, is 3

in the 4th row, the opponent for user=1, is 4

in the 1st & 2nd row, the opponent for user=1, is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT distinct receiver FROM (
SELECT receiver, id FROM items WHERE sender ='1'
UNION
SELECT sender, id FROM items WHERE receiver ='1'
ORDER BY id DESC) sortedtable

10
5
8
3
4
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using Group By:

```
SELECT t.user, max(t.id)
FROM
(
  SELECT receiver as user, id FROM items WHERE sender ='1'
  UNION
  SELECT sender as user, id FROM items WHERE receiver ='1'
) as t
GROUP BY t.user
ORDER BY max(t.id) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e971/1/0

One more option without UNION:

```
SELECT 
  CASE receiver 
    WHEN '1' THEN sender 
    ELSE receiver  
  END as user, 
  max(id) 
FROM items WHERE sender ='1' OR receiver ='1'
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY max(id) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e971/3/0

Comment: Thank you, this seems more advanced as some times need to query again to get the respective id. thanks !!!